# How to create CPU, Memory, Disk Alerts by using an Data Collection Rules

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts, data-collection, azure-monitor

Previously as we have created an alerts (Memory, CPU, Disk) using an Log-Analytics workspace is going to be no-use.

Create Alerts - CPU, Memory, Disk by using an Data Collection Rules.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Monitor data collection is configured using Data Collection Rule which contains details of which data to be collected, how it can be transformed and where to send the data. DCR is replacing the legacy collection methods.

Alerts are created on the data collected using DCR rules. You can create alert by traversing to Alerts tab of Azure Monitor service in Azure Portal.

For further information, on how to create alerts refer [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-create-new-alert-rule?tabs=metric).

Instead of creating alerts from scratch, you can use alert rule recommendations feature which provides recommended list of alerts for a specific resource type. Do note this feature is currently in preview and is only available for few services like virtual machines, AKS resources and log analytics workspace. Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-manage-alert-rules#enable-recommended-alert-rules-in-the-azure-portal-preview